# Derivatives must vanish near a point in any coordinate system

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

These differentiable manifold [notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/%7Ejoyce/Nairobi2019/Hitchin-DifferentiableManifolds.pdf) of Nigel Hitchin argue (on page 16) that

> "on a compact manifold any function has a maximum, and in any
> coordinate system in a neighbourhood of that point, its derivative
> must vanish".

Why is this (that *any* coordinate system must have this zero derivative property at a point)? Does this follow from an argument similar to the chain rule? That when the derivative vanishes in one system, any transformation gets zeroed by these derivatives being zero? It seems difficult to imagine how no coordinate change could alter the derivative, but perhaps it is obvious.

Comment: The fact of a maximum at a point is independent of the coordinate system. Changing the coordinate system will change the nonzero values of the derivative, but not the zero of the derivative at the maximum. You can show this with the chain rule but the geometric argument should be convincing.

Comment: Ok, I suppose in my mind I can add something to each point that varies somehow, skewing a region which is usually flat. Perhaps this is not a change of coordinates though.

Comment: "Skewing a region which is usually flat" is changing the intrinsic geometry of the manifold. Coordinate changes don't do that.

Comment: It may seem simple, but is there a nice way to explain what a change of coordinates actually is, intuitively? I am imagining changing from Cartesian to polar, but I don't seem to get the natural idea, as you say, geometrically.

Comment: Any *real-valued* function. It's important to say that explicitly. Re polar coordinates, remember that that is *not* a valid coordinate system at the origin.

Comment: One way to convince yourself is indeed by using the chain rule. In short, if $\Phi$ is the change of coordinates map (i.e. a diffeomorphism of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $J$ is its Jacobian, then $d(f\circ\Phi)(x) = J(x)df(\Phi(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to the comment asking for a

> way to explain what a change of coordinates actually is, intuitively?

that may also help with the question.

Consider all the paper maps you know of the globe (stay away from the poles for this discussion). On each you have the  the circles of longitude and latitude - which will not be circles. The usual rectangular coordinate system on the rectangular map tells you how to identify points on the globe by their map $(x,y)$ coordinates, so you have a coordinate system for a patch of the globe. Different map projections correspond to different local coordinate systems.

Converting coordinates of a point on the globe from those on one map to those on another is a change of coordinates.

Now think about the height above sea level as a function defined on the globe. It will have a local maximum (in fact, a global maximum) at the top of Mt Everest. If you calculate heights as a function $f$ of $(x,y)$ on any map (in any coordinate system) that function will have a local maximum and horizontal tangent plane at the point corresponding to Mt Everest.

This example suggests the standard vocabulary that describes  manifold structure as an atlas of charts.

Comment: Ok this is very helpful indeed. So basically the function is what has the maximum, and this isn't really affected at all by the coordinate systems used to "name" each point in the manifold. Hence where its values do not change at each point (fixed) by renaming them according to a new coordinate system.

Comment: @apkg That's it exactly.